# Как использовать qwt в UI приложениях?

Tags: c++, qt

Я использую [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). У меня есть файл ksp_ecology_water.ui в котором есть widget:[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
 Как на месте этого виджета отобразить градусник:[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Я уже подключил заголовочный файл и вызвал функцию рисующую градусник:
ksp_ecology_water.cpp:

```
#include "wheelbox.h"

ksp_ecology_water::ksp_ecology_water(QString KPT, double Mkrt, QWidget *parent) :
    _KPT(KPT),
    _Mkrt(Mkrt),
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ksp_ecology_water)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
...
    WheelBox *termometr = new WheelBox( Qt::Vertical, 0 );
    ui->widget->//тут загвоздка
}
```

Код Градусника состоит из двух файлов:

1 wheelbox.h

```
#ifndef WHEELBOX_H
#define WHEELBOX_H

#include <qwidget.h>

class QLabel;
class QwtThermo;
class QwtWheel;

class WheelBox: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WheelBox( Qt::Orientation,
        int type, QWidget *parent = NULL );

private Q_SLOTS:
    void setNum( double v );

private:
    QWidget *createBox( Qt::Orientation, int type );

private:
    QwtWheel *d_wheel;
    QwtThermo *d_thermo;
    QLabel *d_label;
};

#endif
```

2 wheelbox.cpp

```
#include <qlabel.h>
#include <qlayout.h>
#include <qwt_wheel.h>
#include <qwt_thermo.h>
#include <qwt_scale_engine.h>
#include <qwt_transform.h>
#include <qwt_color_map.h>
#include "wheelbox.h"

WheelBox::WheelBox( Qt::Orientation orientation,
        int type, QWidget *parent ):
    QWidget( parent )
{
    QWidget *box = createBox( orientation, type );
    d_label = new QLabel( this );
    d_label->setAlignment( Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop );

    QBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout( this );
    layout->addWidget( box );
    layout->addWidget( d_label );

    setNum( d_wheel->value() );

    connect( d_wheel, SIGNAL( valueChanged( double ) ),
        this, SLOT( setNum( double ) ) );
}

QWidget *WheelBox::createBox(
    Qt::Orientation orientation, int type )
{
    d_wheel = new QwtWheel();
    d_wheel->setValue( 80 );
    d_wheel->setWheelWidth( 20 );
    d_wheel->setMass( 1.0 );

    d_thermo = new QwtThermo();
    d_thermo->setOrientation( orientation );

    if ( orientation == Qt::Horizontal )
    {
        d_thermo->setScalePosition( QwtThermo::LeadingScale );
        d_wheel->setOrientation( Qt::Vertical );
    }
    else
    {
        d_thermo->setScalePosition( QwtThermo::TrailingScale );
        d_wheel->setOrientation( Qt::Horizontal );
    }

    switch( type )
    {
        case 0:
        {
            QwtLinearColorMap *colorMap = new QwtLinearColorMap();
            colorMap->setColorInterval( Qt::blue, Qt::red );
            d_thermo->setColorMap( colorMap );

            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            QwtLinearColorMap *colorMap = new QwtLinearColorMap();
            colorMap->setMode( QwtLinearColorMap::FixedColors );

            int idx = 4;

            colorMap->setColorInterval( Qt::GlobalColor( idx ),
                Qt::GlobalColor( idx + 10 ) );
            for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                colorMap->addColorStop( i / 10.0,
                    Qt::GlobalColor( idx + i ) );
            }

            d_thermo->setColorMap( colorMap );
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            d_wheel->setRange( 10, 1000 );
            d_wheel->setSingleStep( 1.0 );

            d_thermo->setScaleEngine( new QwtLogScaleEngine );
            d_thermo->setScaleMaxMinor( 10 );

            d_thermo->setFillBrush( Qt::darkCyan );
            d_thermo->setAlarmBrush( Qt::magenta );
            d_thermo->setAlarmLevel( 500.0 );

            d_wheel->setValue( 800 );

            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            d_wheel->setRange( -1000, 1000 );
            d_wheel->setSingleStep( 1.0 );
            d_wheel->setPalette( QColor( "Tan" ) );

            QwtLinearScaleEngine *scaleEngine = new QwtLinearScaleEngine();
            scaleEngine->setTransformation( new QwtPowerTransform( 2 ) );

            d_thermo->setScaleMaxMinor( 5 );
            d_thermo->setScaleEngine( scaleEngine );

            QPalette pal = palette();
            pal.setColor( QPalette::Base, Qt::darkGray );
            pal.setColor( QPalette::ButtonText, QColor( "darkKhaki" ) );

            d_thermo->setPalette( pal );
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            d_wheel->setRange( -100, 300 );
            d_wheel->setInverted( true );

            QwtLinearColorMap *colorMap = new QwtLinearColorMap();
            colorMap->setColorInterval( Qt::darkCyan, Qt::yellow );
            d_thermo->setColorMap( colorMap );

            d_wheel->setValue( 243 );

            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            d_thermo->setFillBrush( Qt::darkCyan );
            d_thermo->setAlarmBrush( Qt::magenta );
            d_thermo->setAlarmLevel( 60.0 );

            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            d_thermo->setOriginMode( QwtThermo::OriginMinimum );
            d_thermo->setFillBrush( QBrush( "DarkSlateBlue" ) );
            d_thermo->setAlarmBrush( QBrush( "DarkOrange" ) );
            d_thermo->setAlarmLevel( 60.0 );

            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            d_wheel->setRange( -100, 100 );

            d_thermo->setOriginMode( QwtThermo::OriginCustom );
            d_thermo->setOrigin( 0.0 );
            d_thermo->setFillBrush( Qt::darkBlue );

            break;
        }
    }

    double min = d_wheel->minimum();
    double max = d_wheel->maximum();

    if ( d_wheel->isInverted() )
        qSwap( min, max );

    d_thermo->setScale( min, max );
    d_thermo->setValue( d_wheel->value() );

    connect( d_wheel, SIGNAL( valueChanged( double ) ),
        d_thermo, SLOT( setValue( double ) ) );

    QWidget *box = new QWidget();

    QBoxLayout *layout;

    if ( orientation == Qt::Horizontal )
        layout = new QHBoxLayout( box );
    else
        layout = new QVBoxLayout( box );

    layout->addWidget( d_thermo, Qt::AlignCenter );
    layout->addWidget( d_wheel );

    return box;
}

void WheelBox::setNum( double v )
{
    QString text;
    text.setNum( v, 'f', 2 );

    d_label->setText( text );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам уже сказали как добавить qwt виджет через дизайнер. Если по какой-то причине, вас такой подход не устраивает, то можно сделать это из кода.

Вообще, я адепт того, что все виджеты лучше раскидывать руками из кода. Так вы имеете больший контроль над внешним видом окна, и проблем вроде вашей не возникало бы.

В вашем случае, чтобы все не переделывать, можно пойти на компромисс. Добавить конкретно этот виджет из кода на существующую ui форму. Сделайте следующее:

1. В то место, где у вас должен быть виджет, при помощи дизанера добавьте лайоут. Назовите его `wheelBoxLayout`, например
2. В конструкторе, после вызова `setupUi`, напишите

   ```
   ui->wheelBoxLayout->addWidget(new WheelBox(orientation, type));
   ```

Comment: Ошибка runtime error c++ Стала возникать , когда я стал запускать проект ......Из-за чего может возникнуть такая ошибка ? Библиотеки не те указаны ? ..... Не могу из-за этого проверить этот вариант

Comment: @IvanTriumphov освойте наконец дебаггер и разберитесь, что и где у вас падает

Comment: А как получить значение из этого виджета WheelBox? И записать в переменную

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, надо было запонмить указатель на него. Можно, конечно, и так добраться `WheelBox *wheelBox = qobject_cast<WheelBox *>(ui->wheelBoxLayout->itemAt(0)->widget());`. Но проще сохранить указатель при создании.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb  Я так и не понял как получить значение у меня переменная double Tv= как в неё записать значение которое выставляется в виджете ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, ааа, так у вас именно `WheelBox` никак значение не отдает. Я думал проблема только в том чтобы до него добраться. Это тема для отдельного вопроса

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb WheelBox::WheelBox( Qt::Orientation orientation,
        int type, QWidget *parent ):
    QWidget( parent )
{.... return d_wheel->value();} Так будет отдавать ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, вот поэтому я и предлагаю создать отдельный вопрос. Глаза можно сломать, читая код в комментах. У вас уже есть сеттер `setNum` создайте ему пару - геттер `num`. Если не знаете как, создайте вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72810/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-yrhetatejlb).

Answer (score 2):

1. Положить на UI, QWidget.
2. В контекстном меню (на свежепложенном виджете), выбрать "Promote to ...".
3. Указать имя класса (WheelBox), имя заголовочного файла, с описанием класса (wheelbox.h) и тип базового класса (QWidget).
4. Нажать кнопку [Add].
5. Нажать кнопку [Promote].

В следующий раз, в контекстном меню (на виджетах типа QWidget), появится пункт "Promote to" \ "WheelBox". 
Соответственно, указывать имя заголовочного файла будет необязательно.

Comment: В виджет надо параметры передать . Это не так скорей всего делается. К тому же этот виджет надо добавить еще несколько раз .

Comment: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'WheelBox::WheelBox(QGroupBox*&)'
         widget = new WheelBox(groupBox_5);  Если это проделать будет ошибка
                                         ^

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, это делается именно так, если вы хотите использовать дизайнер

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Я не понимаю как мне передать таким образом параметры ? Qt::Orientation, int type И это же класс, а не виджет . Который рисует градусник

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, ну вынесите эти параметры из конструктора. Задайте их при помощи сеттеров

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb А что за ошибка ? ошибка: no matching function for call to 'WheelBox::WheelBox(QGroupBox*&)'
         widget = new WheelBox(groupBox_5);

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, когда вы используйте ui форму, утилита uic генерирует из нее c++ код. В этом коде создается ваш виджет, и ему в качестве параметра передается родитель `groupBox_5`: `widget = new WheelBox(groupBox_5)`. У но у вас нет конструктора, который принимает только родителя. Отсюда и ошибка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72780/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-yrhetatejlb).